# Tridion Deployment Error

Tags: smarttarget

We are facing an issue while deploying a Smart Target enabled component to the Tridion. I am getting the following exception. Please find below. Please provide few pointers on where we may be going wrong. Thanks in advance.

> 2015-06-09 09:19:09,855 DEBUG SchemaInfoBuilder - Unable to find label for field 'Content' - returning field name instead.
>   2015-06-09 09:19:09,888 INFO  ConfigurationUtility - no publication mapping found for tcm:0-2478-1
>   2015-06-09 09:19:09,888 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH set attribute: attributeId=tcm_2478_477177_8_trigger_value, displayName=Smart Region - Trigger - value, valueId=tcm_2478_477238_tcm_2478_477232_32_trigger_value, values=[chrome]
>   2015-06-09 09:19:09,889 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH set attribute: attributeId=tcm_2478_477177_8_trigger_key, displayName=Smart Region - Trigger - key, valueId=tcm_2478_477238_tcm_2478_477232_32_trigger_key, values=[browser]
>   2015-06-09 09:19:10,228 WARN  CommitPhase - Failure during the post-transaction and the transaction will NOT be rolled-back
>   2015-06-09 09:19:10,230 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to execute onSuccess event in phase: Deployment Commit Phase for transaction: tcm:0-1098126-66560
>   2015-06-09 09:19:10,236 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stacktrace for transaction: tcm:0-1098126-66560
>   com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: **unable to persist the fredhopper XML through the webservice
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.WebserviceDeployer.deploy(WebserviceDeployer.java:50) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]**
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.utils.SmartTargetXMLUtils.persistFredhopperXML(SmartTargetXMLUtils.java:176) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperOutputBuilder.persistFredhopperXML(FredhopperOutputBuilder.java:119) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperDeployerModule.process(FredhopperDeployerModule.java:76) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:77) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.onSuccess(CommitPhase.java:116) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runSafeEvent(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:240) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:101) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [na:1.6.0_25]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [na:1.6.0_25]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_25]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_25]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_25]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_25]
>   **Caused by: com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: webservice received but failed to deploy fredhopper xml. see webservice logs for details.**
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.WebserviceDeployer.deploy(WebserviceDeployer.java:44) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       ... 17 common frames omitted

Comment: From the log you posted it is clear that it was able to contact the SmartTarget Deployment web service, but that said service failed to deploy the files. There could be any number of reasons for that, so you really do need to look at the webservice log file, as suggested.